# Font not displaying properly while compiling using xelatex

Tags: xetex, fontspec

The Devanagari font not displaying properly in xelatex
I have tried with other devanagari fonts and same problem remains

```
\documentclass{article}

%!TEX program=xelatex

\usepackage[margin=.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}

% Devanagari
\newcommand{\Devanagari}[1]{\fontspec{Uttara}#1}

\begin{document}
    \Devanagari{मकडि का कान}
\end{document}
```

Ideal Output : [Libre Office] 
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdOGT.png] 
Actual Output : 
 [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqL3g.png]

Comment: The Uttara font is not part of TeX. I downloaded it separately, and instead of compiling with xelatex, I compiled with lualatex. Same problem. I conclude that the font does not interact well with TeX, unless some additional code is provided. Does TeX have a suitable substitute font?

Comment: Thanks for mentioning. It also had problem with other fonts like Noto Sans Devanagari too. As mentioned in answer it worked just fine.

Comment: This article discuss about [LaTeX/Internationalization](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Internationalization). You can use tex fonts to write in other language. I generally prefer a font just for the looks, it doesn't matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Script` option:

```
\newcommand\Devanagari[1]{\fontspec[Script=Devanagari]{Uttara}#1}
```

Comment: Interesting. I thought that the use of OpenType script was for language-specific character alternatives (such as Turkish i with/without dot). Did not realize that it also was used for other purposes.